# How do I remove all files from wtihin a certain directory except for a child directory of that directory?

Tags: bash, find, directory, rm

I’m using bash shell.  I have this command to delete all JAR files within a particular directory

```
find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/ -name '*.jar' -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm
```

However, I want to modify the above so that it will delete all JAR files except those within the “~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/myapp”.  How do I modify the above command to exclude removing JAR files from that specific directory while removing from all others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-prune` option to skip that directory

```
find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco -path ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/myapp -prune -o -name '*.jar' -exec rm -r {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(
  cd ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco
  find . -path ./myapp -prune -o -type f -name '*.jar' -print0 | ...
)
```

Adding `-type f` to restrict the condition, since when you want to match JAR files only. And also, you used `-print0`, it's likely that your `find` supports `-delete`, so you can use:

```
(
  cd ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco
  find . -path ./myapp -prune -o -type f -name '*.jar' -delete
)
```

POSIXly:

```
(
  cd ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco
  find . -path ./myapp -prune -o -type f -name '*.jar' -exec rm -f {} +
)
```

With GNU find, you can use `-execdir` to avoid [`-exec` race condition](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec), see also some [security considerations in GNU find manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Security-Considerations).

You should always use `-delete` when available.